# ¿Como obtengo el indice de un numero en un vector en C++?

Tags: array, lista, c++11

Necesito hallar el indice de un numero del vector en C++, particularmente del minimo del mismo arreglo.

Quiero hacer lo mismo que, por ejemplo, en Python hace el metodo `.index()` en una lista de python, pero con un vector en C++.

Ejemplo en python de lo que quiero hacen en C++:  `arr.index(min(arr))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas usando vectores dinámicos, puedes usar `std::min_element` para obtener el lugar del minimo elemento en el vector, para despues usar `std::distance` que arroja la distancia entre dos posiciones del vector, entonces usaremos la primer posicion `vec.begind()` y el elemento encontrado `min`, eso te arrojara el indice del menor elemento.

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec = {8,3,6,11,10};
auto min= std::min_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
std::cout<<std::distance(vec.begin(), min)<<std::endl;
```

Salida

> 1